# $\log x =Cx^4$ has only one root. Find C

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, roots, gre-exam

$\log x =Cx^4$ has only one root. Find C.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Do you take derivative on both sides?

I am thinking C equals 0. Am I correct on that?

Comment: Since it is presumably an equation to be solved for $x$, it is not true for all $x$ so taking derivatives isn't valid. For example one wouldn't solve $x^2+3x+2=0$ by going to $2x+3=0$ via derivative.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks! I am also thinking exponentiate both sides.

Comment: @Amzoti I see it. At x = 1, it becomes $e^c - 1 =0$, so c must be zero.

Answer (score 3):

Generally a function has a root, not an equation. I am assuming here that the 'root' is really a solution to the equation.

Plot $\log x$ and $cx^4$ simultaneously for various values of $c$; you will notice the following:

- For large positive $c$, there are no intersection points.
- At some critical positive $c$, the two graphs are tangent with one intersection point.
- For positive $c$ smaller than $c_{crit}$, there are two intersections (one near 1, and one which tends to infinity).
- At $c=0$, there is only the root left at $x=1$ -- the other root has escaped to infinity.
- For negative $c$, there is always precisely one solution for positive $x$, tending to 0 as $c \to -\infty$.

To find the value of $c_{crit}$, note that the graphs must be tangent and differentiate to find that 
$$
\log x = c_{crit}x^4 ~~\text{and}~~ \frac 1 x = 4c_{crit}x^3 ~~\text{so that after some algebra,}~~ x^4 = \frac 1 {4c}, c_{crit} = \frac 1 {4e} .
$$
Hence there is precisely one solution for $c=0,c=\frac 1 {4e}$ with values $x = 1,e^{1/4}$ respectively. If negative $c$ are permitted, then all negative $c$ work too, with precise root given by a Lambert-W expression.

Comment: OP said there is $\large\tt one$ root. So, $\large C = 1/4e$. $\large C$ isn't know at the beginning.

Comment: I examined how many solutions exist for different values of $C$; the values for which exactly one solution exists are $C \in \{1/4e\} \cup (-\infty,0]$.

Comment: It is simply not true that the term "root" doesn't refer to the solution of an equation.  In fact there is a long history of using the term "root" to refer to the solution any equation and the term "zero", as in "a zero of the function $f$", to refer to a solution of the specific equation $f(x) = 0$.  This distinction is illustrated in Marden's *Geometry of Polynomials* (1949), for example.  See [Theorem (33,1)](http://books.google.ca/books?id=amZNytzH_FwC&pg=PA152).  The same convention is used in Boas' *Entire Functions* (1954) (except in one theorem, strangely). (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) On the other hand, many people also use the phrase "roots of a function $f$" to refer to these solutions of $f(x) = 0$; both usages are very common now, though one convention may be preferred over the other.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks for that bit of history! I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @EugeneShvarts How do you get from $x^4 = \frac{1}{4c}$ to $c_{crit} = \frac{1}{4e}$. Can you show me that algebra?

Comment: @JamesLee We solve the two equations obtained (for function value and derivative) as a system in the two variables $x$ and $c$. I get $x^4= 1/4c$ by the second equation, and then plug that into the first equation to obtain $\log x = 1/4 \log (x^4) = 1/4 \log (1/4c) = c*(1/4c)$, so that $\log (1/4c) = 1$ and so $c = 1/4e$.

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the function
$$
f(x)=\log x-Cx^4
$$
which is defined for $x>0$. We have $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=-\infty$ and
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if $C \le 0$},\\
-\infty & \text{if $C > 0$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Compute the derivative
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-4Cx^3=\frac{1-Cx^4}{x}
$$
from which we deduce that the derivative is everywhere positive when $C\le 0$. So, for $C\le 0$ the function $f$ is strictly increasing and the equation $f(x)=0$ has a unique solution.

Let's now look at the $C>0$ case, where the derivative vanishes only at $C^{-1/4}$ which therefore is where the function $f$ attains its maximum.

If the maximum value is positive, the equation $f(x)=0$ has two solutions, if it's negative there will be no solution, if the maximum value is $0$ the solution is unique.

Since
$$
f(C^{-1/4})=-\frac{1}{4}\log C - 1
$$
we can conclude that the value we're looking for is
$$
C=e^{-1/4}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Find the value of $f'(x)$ at $c$, when $f(x) =\log x$, $c=e$.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$

$\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_{0}}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}\def\e{\mathrm{e}}$

\begin{align} 
\ln(x)&=c\,x^4
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

I'm surprised that the 
[Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
was only briefly mentioned in [one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/523360/122782),
since it's purpose is 
to greatly simplify the solutions of exactly this king of equations.

We just need to transform \eqref{1} to the form $u\exp(u)=v$,
apply Lambert W function to both sides of it 
and check the argument of $\W(v)$
to find out the number of the real solutions:

\begin{align} 
4\,\ln(x) &=4\,c\,x^4
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\tfrac1{x^4}\,\ln(x^4) &=4\,c
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
-\tfrac1{x^4}\,\ln(x^4) &=-4\,c
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\tfrac1{x^4}\,\ln(\tfrac1{x^4}) &=-4\,c
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\ln(\tfrac1{x^4})\,\exp(\ln(\tfrac1{x^4})) &=-4\,c
\quad
(\text{ this is the sought form } u\exp(u)=v
,\quad u=\ln(\tfrac1{x^4}),\quad
v=-4\,c)
\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\W\left(\ln(\tfrac1{x^4})\,\exp(\ln(\tfrac1{x^4}))\right) &=\W(-4\,c)
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
\ln(\tfrac1{x^4}) &=\W(-4\,c)
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
\tfrac1{x^4} &=\exp(\W(-4\,c))
\tag{9}\label{9}
,\\
x^4 &=\exp(-\W(-4\,c))
\tag{10}\label{10}
,\\
x &=\pm \exp(-\tfrac14\,\W(-4\,c))
\tag{11}\label{11}
.
\end{align}

At this point we need to recall that $x\le0$ are not solutions to \eqref{1}
(spurious roots were introduced in step \eqref{3}),
so we need to check only positive solutions

\begin{align} 
x &=\exp(-\tfrac14\,\W(-4\,c))
\tag{12}\label{12}
.
\end{align}

In \eqref{12} the argument of 
$\W(-4\,c)$ is $-4\,c$, hence

there are no real solutions for $c>\tfrac1{4\e}$,
there are one real solution 
\begin{align} 
x &=\exp(-\tfrac14\,\Wp(-4\,c))\quad \text{for}\quad c\le0
\\
\text{and}\quad
x &=\exp(-\tfrac14\,\Wp(-\tfrac1{\e}))=\exp(-\tfrac14\,\Wm(-\tfrac1{\e}))
=\exp(\tfrac14)
\quad \text{for}\quad c=\tfrac1{4\e}
,
\end{align}

and there are two real solutions

\begin{align} 
x_0 &=\exp(-\tfrac14\,\Wp(-4\,c))
,\\
\text{and}\quad
x_{-1} &=\exp(-\tfrac14\,\Wm(-4\,c))
\quad \text{for}\quad c \in(0,\tfrac1{4\e})
.
\end{align}

$\endgroup$