# solution set in $\mathbb{C}$ of $ z^{\frac1{z}}=\left(\frac1{z}\right)^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ what can be said about the solution set of:
$$
z^{\frac1{z}}=\left(\frac1{z}\right)^z
$$
aside from the fact that it contains the fourth roots of unity?

I will add as a footnote something that I only realized whilst reading through the comments, that the symmetry of the problem suggests examining the intersection of two sets in $\mathbb{C}^2$ defined by:
$$
z^w = w^z
$$
and
$$
wz = 1
$$

further footnote: one small bit of progress is to see what happens if $z=e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ real and $ -\pi \le \theta \lt \pi$. plugging this value in gives:
$$
\theta \cos \theta = n \pi
$$
so for $n=0$ either $\theta =0$ or $\cos \theta =0$, and if $n=1$ then $\theta = -\pi$ so this is a derivation of the four solutions satisfying $z^4 = 1$ which were already fairly obvious by "inspection".

I am very lacking in knowledge of complex analysis, so perhaps someone with more experience can determine if each of these solutions is an isolated zero, or if there is some way of showing that for any or all of them other solutions can be found in an arbitrarily small neighbourhood - i.e. the four solutions on the unit circle might be points of accumulation of a larger set of solutions.

for example if we are very near $z=1$ we may (naively) set $z=1+dz$ and $\frac1{z}=1-dz$ so the constraint requires:
$$
(1+dz)^{1-dz}=(1-dz)^{1+dz}
$$
or
$$
\frac{1+dz}{1-dz} = (1-dz^2)^{dz}
$$ 
applying the binomial theorem in a simplistic way gives $dz=0$, but since the functions $(1+dz)^{-dz}=(1-dz)^{dz}$ are (?) for general complex values of $dz$ infinitely many-valued, this naive analysis may not rule out something like a series of solutions lying on a set of spirals converging around $z=1$. however this is little more than hand-waving, and i am out of my depth, so unable to take such an argument further.

Comment: If we take $z$ as an exponent of both sides, then divide by $z$, we get $1=\frac {1^{z^2}}{z^{z^2+1}}$, or $$z^{z^2+1}=1^{z^2}=1$$

Comment: @Thomas, why did you remove the ([tag:roots]) tag?  This question is specifically about the roots of the equation.

Comment: This problem is about solutions of an equation. A root is different from a solution - a root is a zero of a function. Usually in reference to polynomial functions, but sometimes not. This problem is just an equation, not a question about roots. @AntonioVargas In particular, since $a^b$ is not a function in complex numbers, this is not a question about roots.

Comment: @abiessu $1^{z^2}\neq 1$, at least not always. $a^b$ is a multivalued function on the complex numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, the term "root" is used to mean the solution of an equation as well.  I wrote about this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523319/log-x-cx4-has-only-one-root-find-c/523360#comment1119501_523360) a while back.

Comment: Furhter, the tag ([tag:roots]) has been used in this sense of the word.  There is precedent.

Comment: I missed my edit window to correct it to $e^{2ki\pi z^2}$, @thomasandrews

Comment: presumably there is a submanifold(?) of $\mathbb{C}^2$ for the equation $z^w = w^z$. so the question is asking about the intersection of this with the curve $zw=1$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews btw Thomas, thanks very much for editing the title so it reads as it should

Comment: @David Holden Raising one arbitrary complex number to the power of another arbitrary complex number is not a well-defined operation, so it is not obvious exactly what you are asking.

Comment: The large roots of the related equation $\exp[(z+1/z)\log z] = 1$ are asymptotic to $2\pi n i/W(2\pi n i)$ as $n \to \infty$, $n \in \Bbb Z$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  Choosing a different branch of $\log$ corresponds to choosing a different branch of the Lambert W function.